# How to calculate the used cell range of an Excel 2007 file

Tags: excel-2007

Kindly let us know how to calculate the used cell range (i.e.,the cells that contain some data) for a given Excel 2007 or Excel 2010 file.

Thanks and Regards,
Sharpsubbu

Answer (score 0):

To **count** the number of used cells on a **worksheet** use:

```
Sub HowManyUsedCells()
    Dim total As Long
    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        On Error Resume Next
            total = .SpecialCells(xlConstants).Count
            total = total + .SpecialCells(xlFormulas).Count
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    MsgBox total
End Sub
```

To **locate** the used cells on a **worksheet**, this:

```
Sub WhereAreTheUsedCells()
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Address
End Sub
```

will work *most* of the time.